# How can i change the name or message of a JavaScript Error object used in Sentry?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I have a JavaScript error object that I have caught in code. It has a name, message, stack etc that I want to log at the backend. I am using sentry for that. But before logging I want to change the name or the message of the error.

What will be the best way to do it?
I tried creating a new error and adding the original error as `cause`, but that did not work with sentry. It just logs the error passed as the cause of the new error.

```js
new Error('Additional error message', { cause: originalError });
```

I need the rest of the properties of the error to remain the same, just need to change the name or message.

Comment: What do you mean by "before logging"? Can you show the complete code, as well as your Sentry JS configuration? Did you re-`throw` the new error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've made errors a bit readable with this:

when you capture exception, add transactionName to `scope`.

you can also enhance event in `beforeSend` method

```
Sentry.captureException(error, (scope) => {
        ...
        scope.setTransactionName(`my custom title for error`);
        return scope;
    });
```

[image: Sentry error example:]

Comment: Hi, will this be searchable in sentry? meaning, can i search with "my custom title for error" ?

Answer (score 2):

A super helpful thing you can do to accomplish this is actually create your own custom error types. This can be done by simply using a class that extends the Error constructor, like so:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super();
    this.name = "MyError";
    this.message = message;
  }
}
try {
  throw new MyError('this is my error')
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err instanceof Error);
  console.log(err.message);
  console.log(err.name);
  console.log(err.stack);
}
```

```js
class ExtendedError extends Error {
  constructor(message, { cause }) {
    super();
    this.name = "ExtendedError";
    this.message = message;
    // set the cause to maintain linkage to the original error
    this.cause = cause;
  }
}
try {
  throw new Error('Something bad happened!');
} catch (err) {
  let extendedError = new ExtendedError('Additional details', { cause: err });
  console.log(extendedError instanceof Error);
  console.log(extendedError.message);
  console.log(extendedError.name);
  console.log(extendedError.cause.stack);
  console.log(extendedError.stack);
}
```

Comment: Given that `.cause` is standardised, you should prefer it over `.originalError `

Comment: This will work for me, but instead of copying all properties individually, can we somehow "clone" the error object and update the message?